# C'è un verbo per indicare il rumore che fa la grandine?

Tags: word-choice

Ho trovato un passaggio in inglese in cui *the hail rattles*, e immagino si riferisca al rumore di urti ripetuti dei chicchi di grandine su una superficie solida, ad esempio i vetri.

Abbiamo un verbo, in italiano, idoneo ad indicare tale rumore?

Se si trattasse di pioggia sui vetri, *scroscio* andrebbe bene. Ma per la grandine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Io direi che una possibilità è *crepitare*, che si usa per varie cose, grandine compresa, vedi voce Treccani sotto , in cui  c'è la citazione *sul tetto salta L’orrida grandin crepitando (Pindemonte)*: divertente, non avrei mai associato *orrido* a *grandine*, chi sa che gli passava per la testa a Pindemonte.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/crepitare/

E anche qualche sinonimo di *crepitare* come *picchiettare* (se è grandine piccola) e *tamburellare*, verbi che trovo entrambi brutti e scontati, ma è questione di gusti e, se si deve tradurre,  di cosa si deve tradurre.

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/crepitare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/